# mac os double-click command to execute pdflate can't find local style file

Tags: mac, bash

I am writing a mac os double-click  bash command file   X.command  to execute a sequence of pdflatex-ing of various LaTeX files.  In the directory containing the files there is an included style file BICA.sty that the LaTeX Files use.

```
>ls
BICA.sty    X.command   cover.tex
```

A MWE for X.command is

```
#!/bin/bash
DIRNAME=`dirname "$0"`
pdflatex "$DIRNAME"/cover.tex
read -p
```

When I open a finder window and double-click X.command  I get this error:

! LaTeX Error: File `BICA.sty' not found.

**Note:**

1. there will be several files in the directory to pdflatex.
2. It all works fine if I run it from a terminal window command line.
3. I am writing this command for less sophisticated users to use.

Comment: don't do that, do `cd $DIRNAME; pdflatex cover` so it runs from the files directory

Comment: When I do that I get: ! I can't find file `cover'.

Comment: Does DIRNAME have spaces in it? Then use `cd "$DIRNAME"`. Is there some reason the "less sophisticated user" shouldn't just use a front end to the distribution like TeXShop? TeXShop has some engines that use latexmk which take care of all processing (with some help if sosmething sophisticaed is going to be used). Finally, what distribution did you install?

Comment: as Herb says you'll need quotes if there spaces in the directory name.

Comment: Yes DIRNAME has a space in it and the double quotes worked.  I never use these front end engines, so I don't know how you instruct one to first pdflatex these 20 files (twice) before doing this last one (twice) for example. So I was building a simple bash script that he could run.  I think I have installed Texlive but I never use the front end.

Comment: @DonKreher: I'm trying to understand what you are trying to do. You say 20 files. Are they related to a single final document, separate documents or something else?

Comment: @Herb Schulz: I have 20 pdf manuscripts to be included into a single manuscript. The 20 manuscripts are written in Latex and must be  pdflatex-ed first before they can be included in a latex file that will be later pdflatex-ed.  It all works great now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input files are always relative to the working directory not the directory with the file, so arrange that the working directory is the directory with the file.

use:

```
cd "$DIRNAME"; pdflatex cover
```